# SQL to search based on record

Tags: sql-server

I have a records where I want to filter them based on some condition. When I add first condition then it works but when I add multiple conditions then I am not getting expected result:

Data:

```
ScheduleID  ScheduledStartDateTime  Query
7857        2017-05-27 16:00:00.000 WHILE (1=1) BEGIN UPDATE TOP (3000) MainItemPOS SET Deleted = 1 WHERE MainItemID  = 276044 AND ConceptID  = 2120 AND 1 = Case  WHEN Deleted <> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IF @@RowCount=0 BREAK; END 
7856        2017-05-27 11:00:00.000 WHILE (1=1) BEGIN UPDATE TOP (3000) MainItemPOS SET Deleted = 0 WHERE MainItemID  = 276045 AND ConceptID  = 2120 AND 1 = Case  WHEN Deleted <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IF @@RowCount=0 BREAK; END
```

Query: This gives me these two rows which is fine.

```
SELECT *
FROM ScheduledBulkUpdate(nolock) SBU
INNER JOIN ScheduledBulkUpdateRecurring(nolock) SBR ON SBR.BatchId = SBU.BatchId
WHERE 
SBU.Query LIKE('% ConceptID  = 2120 %')
```

Now I just want record with `MainItemID  = 276044` so I am using this query then I am not getting desired result. If I use `OR` then also I won't get desired result.

```
SELECT *
FROM ScheduledBulkUpdate(nolock) SBU
INNER JOIN ScheduledBulkUpdateRecurring(nolock) SBR ON SBR.BatchId = SBU.BatchId
WHERE 
SBU.Query LIKE('% ConceptID  = 2120 %')
AND SBU.Query LIKE('% MainItemID  = 276044 %')
```

Do I need to use sub-query? If I change my conditon to `MainItemID  = 276044 AND ConceptID  = 2120` in first query then it will work but I am curious about this approach.

Comment: If you're not getting the desired result, then what result are you getting?   By the way, in TSQL we don't use parenthesis with the `LIKE` operator.   I'm not sure if that could be the cause of unexpected results or not though.

Comment: @TabAlleman That query returns no results. Parenthesis don't make any difference.

Comment: You should be getting the desired results if your query and data are really both what you say they are.  It's possible that the white space in the data isn't what you think it is.   To test it try changing the last `LIKE` operator to `LIKE('%MainItemID%=%276044%')`   Just to test and see if it returns results.

Comment: @TabAlleman Cleaning up white space did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I get suspicious any time an EQUALS or LIKE operator doesn't return expected results and either side of the operation has white space.  The white space may look like blank space characters on your screen, but it could be compressed by your software, it could be TAB characters, and it could contain invisible characters.

Use Wild cards to eliminate the white space, or use a hex editor to see what the white space actually contains, and you will gain more insight into what's going on.